# Intranet domain name

Tags: iis, domain, domain-name-system, intranet

I have setup an intranet with my organization. 
Is it possible to have the domain companyName.home?
I'm a complete newbie to this and I don't know what the limitations are, normally, for intranet domain names.

Thanks!

Comment: A similar question about "internal" domains: http://serverfault.com/questions/270712/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-domain/270749#270749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert, but internally on your own network you can do what you like ;-)..

If you configure your local machines (the ones you want to access this site at least) with a DNS server that has a record saying that "companyName.Home" is 192.168.1.whatever then thats where the names will get resolved to.

You could call it google.com and it would work.. but google would not.

often .local is used at the top level domanin (right most name) as AFAIK it is reserved and will never beon the internet.

If your TLD does not exist on the internet its a bonus (AFAIK) as it means there can be no overlap in routing or authentication with the public internet. EDIT this looks not to be the case see links below..

EDIT: don't use .local (see comments) but idid find tis relevant question serverfault:

[Using .local for internal websites](https://serverfault.com/questions/47087/using-local-for-internal-websites)

and

[Top level domain/domain suffix for private network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-for-private-networks/17566)

they seem to be saying best practice is to use a real TLD.. have a look for yourself though.

You can set up CNAMEs and alternate A records for servers too that allow you to have short names for internal services and sites. though I don't know best practice on this I have certainly seen things like "http://intranet/" setup in quite a few places.

Probably best to ask the question again over on serverfault.. the experts are over there ;-) but hopefully you have some extra ideas to discuss it with them.  Also there are many questions relating to this over there..

Comment: .local is used by the zeroconf protocol.

Comment: there you go! ha ha I was just having a read over on server fault! I will stick to .internal then in future I guess.. I have worked at a few places with .local interesting

Comment: Thanks. I haven't seen my company use .local normally infrastructure sets us up with server names such as bg00web0001 so I type in the browser http://bg00web0001/ and it takes me to the intranet I setup. I would like to simplify it and ask if they could do something like companyName so its http://companyName/ Do you think that's possible?

Comment: If you have an IT department or someone who looks after your dns server ask them to set up a cname (again i am not an expert) and that can mean that you just type "intranet/" in the browser and go straight to it.. though let me check serverfault again ;-)

Comment: note bg00web0001 is the host name, but it will have a fully qualified domain name FQDN if its on a domiain e.g. bg00web0001.companyName.something..

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 suggestions on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Pseudo-domains - .site and .internal, but there is no real standard yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a DNS record to your internal DNS server that points to the web server.